# laravel 4.1.28 , symfony/security suggests packages

Tags: symfony, laravel-4

today, an update of my laravel website to 4.1.28 also installed symfony/security. This suggests 4 packages:

```
symfony/security suggests installing symfony/class-loader (For using the ACL generateSql script)
symfony/security suggests installing symfony/validator (For using the user password constraint)
symfony/security suggests installing doctrine/dbal (For using the built-in ACL implementation)
symfony/security suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using the expression voter)
```

I am not sure whether I need the packages. How are the packages installed? Add them to composer.json or just composer install .. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I'd say, if you don't know what you'd need it for... you probably don't need it. However, if you're interested in what these packages do, I suggest you look them up at packagist.org. For example, the first package is described here: https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/class-loader and if you click the canonical you end up at the Github repo giving you more information.

To install the package, follow instructions from packagist (ie add `"symfony/class-loader": "2.5.*@dev"` to the require object in your composer.json) and run `composer update`.